# how we can edit css for adaptive card? Azure Bot Framework V4 , nodejs, botbuilder-feedback

Tags: css, azure, botframework, chatbot, adaptive-cards

i have used the adaptive card for feedback response using azure bot framework v4. Code has been developed using nodejs.

Module: botbuilder-feedback, now how to style those yes/ no buttons
[image: botbuilder suggested action]

Now can anybody help me out on how to change the css adaptive card, as also for feedback actions. 
how to disable submit button after feedback has been given once.

[image]

Comment: Could you clarify your question please.

Comment: What channel will your bot be running on? The channel makes a big difference on how (and if) you can style the adaptive card.

Comment: webChat channel used for our chatbot

Comment: @BeschtPlaier , i have used botbuilder-feeback supported npm successfully, now displaying an adaptive card for  suggestedAction (NO). For that adaptive card i need to make submit button clicked only once or somehow replace the adaptive card with user response only.

Comment: Please reference this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57777087/3962636).