# Dialog interruptions in MS Bot Framework V4- Node.js

Tags: node.js, botframework, azure-bot-service

I am working on a bot in which I am using a waterfall dialog with some prompts to gather information from the user. The dialog is getting triggered by a button click on an adaptive card.
Now if a user clicks the button, go into the dialog mode, scroll up and clicks the same action button (might be a different action button too), what are the possible options that MS bot service provide to handle such scenarios where:

1. I can let the user know of the existing dialog mode.
2. I can pause the flow until the user receives a response for the second requested action item and
   continue from where the conversation left off.

Comment: You can always "disable" the card, as described in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57777087/3962636). But, it is also important to note that it depends on the channel your bot is being used in. For instance, Teams supports updating a previous activity allowing a card's buttons to be disabled. Web Chat does not. You're mileage will vary with other channels (Facebook, Slack, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Use suggested actions that are hidden after being clicked or use adaptive cards and
the communities [adaptive card prompt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@botbuildercommunity/dialog-prompts)