# How to disable adaptive card submit button in microsoft chatbot?

Tags: botframework, chatbot, adaptive-cards

I'm using an adaptive card and I want to disable the submit button if the user has clicked on the submit button.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Disable Button after single use in a adaptive card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57766022/how-to-disable-button-after-single-use-in-a-adaptive-card)

Comment: Are you still working on this?